# Is it good pratice to hide $_GET in URL with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, security, url

Let me show you a simple example to demonstrate it.

You got this URL :

```
www.bowling.com/account.php?id=30&pref=t,s,m&cr=32
```

Then, with .htaccess you do this following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Your-Account/Identity/$1/?$ account.php?id=$1&pref=$2&cr=$3 [flag(s) u want]
```

Now, instead of having the first URL, y'all can guess, I got this back :

```
www.bowling.com/account.php?Identity/30/
```

The two next $_GET var are now invisible in your URL. Is this a good security secure or just a waste of time? What's your opinion?

Comment: Usually it's better idea to store this kind of stuff in Session, and use GET only in the REST-way. Or send the form via POST and then redirect to a nicer url.

Comment: Security-wise there is no difference. If data is sent from the client to your server, it doesn't matter how it is sent. You should treat it like it's evil.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ and it might have already been answered there if you search for "SEO", "query string" and similar terms.